# Consider the function $f(x) = \frac{\text{max}\space (x, \frac {1}{x})}{\text{min}(x, \frac 1x)}$ when $x ≠ 0;$ $f(x) = 1$ when $x = 0.$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

Consider the function $f(x) = \frac{\text{max}\space (x, \frac {1}{x})}{\text{min}(x, \frac 1x)}$ when $x
≠ 0;$ $f(x) = 1$ when $x = 0.$ Then

$(a).\space \lim_{x\to 0+} f(x) = 0$

$(b).\space \lim_{x\to 0-} f(x) = 0$

$ (c).\space$$f(x)$ is continuous for all $x ≠ 0$

$(d).\space f$ is differentiable for all $x ≠ 0.$

My solution goes like this:

> We first try to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x).$ Now, we observe, that, as $x\to 0+$ ( i.e $x>0$ and $x\to 0$ ) we have, $\text{max}\space (x, \frac {1}{x})=\frac1x$ and $\text{min}\space (x, \frac {1}{x})=x.$ Similarly, as $x\to 0-$ ( i.e $x<0$ and $x\to 0$ ) we have, $$\text{max}\space (x, \frac {1}{x})=x$$ and $$\text{min}\space (x, \frac {1}{x})=\frac 1x.$$ Thus, $$\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{\text{max}\space (x, \frac {1}{x})}{\text{min}(x, \frac 1x)}=\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac {\frac1x}{x}=\frac{1}{x^{2}}=+\infty.$$ Hence, option $a$ is incorrect. Now, we try to evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0-} f(x).$ We see, that $$\lim_{x\to 0-} f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0-}\frac{\text{max}\space (x, \frac {1}{x})}{\text{min}(x, \frac 1x)}=\lim_{x\to 0-}\frac {x}{\frac1x}=x^{2}=0.$$ Hence, we see, that option $b$ is correct. Now, we check for option $c.$ We have $$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{\text{max}\space (x, \frac {1}{x})}{\text{min}(x, \frac 1x)}.$$ Now, we can two cases:
>
> Case 1: $(\text{max}(x,\frac 1x),\text{min}(x,\frac 1x))=(x,\frac 1x)$
>
> Case 2: $(\text{max}(x,\frac 1x),\text{min}(x,\frac 1x))=(\frac 1x,x)$
>
> Thus, for the 1st case, we have, $$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{\text{max}\space (x, \frac {1}{x})}{\text{min}(x, \frac 1x)}=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{x}{\frac 1x}=\lim_{x\to c}x^2=c^2$$ and similarly, for the 2nd case, we have,$$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{\text{max}\space (x, \frac {1}{x})}{\text{min}(x, \frac 1x)}=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{\frac1x}{x}=\lim_{x\to c}\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{1}{c^2}.$$ Since, $c\neq 0$, we can say, $f(x)$ is continuous for all $x ≠ 0$ and hence option $c$ is correct. Now, we see, if $f(x)=\frac{x}{\frac 1x}=x^2$ ( from Case 1 ), then $f'(x)=2x$ and $f(x)=\frac{\frac 1x}{x}=\frac{1}{x^2}$ (from Case 2) and $f'(x)=-2(\frac{1}{x^3}), x\neq 0.$ Now, we check differentiability at $x=1$ then $L'=\lim_{x\to 1-}\frac{\frac{\text{max}\space (x, \frac {1}{x})}{\text{min}(x, \frac 1x)}-1}{x-1}.$ We note, if $x>0$ and $\frac 1x>x$, then $x^2<1\implies 0<x<1$ and $\frac 1x<x$, then $x^2>1\implies x>1$. Hence, $L'=\lim_{x\to 1-}\frac{\frac 1x-1}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1-}\frac{1-x}{x(x-1)}=\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{-1}{x}=1.$ Now, if $$L_1'=\lim_{x\to 1+}\frac{\frac{\text{max}\space (x, \frac {1}{x})}{\text{min}(x, \frac 1x)}-1}{x-1}=L,$$ then $f'(1)$ exists. Now, $$L_1'=\lim_{x\to 1+}\frac{\frac{\text{max}\space (x, \frac {1}{x})}{\text{min}(x, \frac 1x)}-1}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1+}\frac{x-1}{x-1}=1\neq L'.$$ Thus, $f'(1)$ does not exist and hence, $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=1.$ So,  option $d$ is incorrect.

Is the above solution valid? If not, where is it going wrong? I am not quite getting it.

Comment: Make a sketch of the graph of the function (you can use Wolfram Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+max%28x%2C+1%2Fx%29%2Fmin%28x%2C+1%2Fx%29%2C+x%3D-2...2). Then re-check your answer about differentiability. What happens at $x= \pm 1$?

Comment: @MartinR I have edited my solution. Mind taking a look at it now?

Comment: Martin R You are right. I correct it.

Comment: You should begin by converting : $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1/x^2 &  (0<x\le 1) \ or \  (x \le -1)\\ x^2 & \ (x \ge 1) \ or \  (-1 \le x <0) \end{cases}$$